# Honeybadger projectRoot with webpack

Tags: webpack, vuejs2

I have a Vue2 project using `@vue/cli` v3. I added the `@honeybadger-io/vue` library. All is working and notifications are showing. However, while trying to get the sourceMaps and deployments working automatically, I hit a snag.

One of the config options is `projectRoot`. I can't tell what the value should be.

From the docs:

> Honeybadger can separate your application code from your dependencies and vendor code when you tell us the path to your application code in your stack traces. ... When using a source map, `projectRoot` needs to be the path to your application code inside the source map. If you use webpack, then you probably want `'webpack:///./'`

This is in part to help reduce noise. Looking at my errors in honeybadger, there are two main places they come from.

1 is `webpack:///./src/*`. This is from files I wrote throwing an error.

2 is `webpack:///./node_modules/*`. This is from libraries throwing an error.

I want to record the node_module throwing the error as well, but I want as little noise and extraneous paths as possible.

Would I use `webpack:///./` as the `projectRoot` or `webpack:///./src/` since all my files are in the `src` dir? It says 'path to your application code' to separate the dependencies and vendor code, so does it only need the path to MY application code or ALL application code, including `node_modules`?

It seems both work. I can't tell the difference when I try either option, but that doesn't mean they are both right. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full blown answer, but if anyone is looking in the future, I got it all set up flawlessly with `webpack:///./` as the `projectRoot`. I guess it makes sense since that is literally the project root directory.